# How to calculate function points

Tags: theory, computation-theory, function-points

This is a question about theoretical computing. I have came through a question like below;

Consider a project with the following functional units :

- Number of user inputs = 50
- Number of user outputs = 40
- Number of user enquiries = 35
- Number of user files = 06
- Number of external interfaces = 04

Assuming all complexity adjustment factors and weighing factors as average, the function points for the project will be;

The answer is 672. How is this calculated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about business math, not programming as defined by the help center.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## 1. Typical complexity averages are as follows:

[image: Table of function-points average]

> **AVERAGE complexity weights** = `{4, 5, 4, 10, 7}` for the 5 complexities respectively.

---

## 2. Typical Characteristic weights are as follows:

[image: Table of characteristics weights]

> **AVERAGE characteristic weight** = 3.

---

## 3. Function point = `FP` = `UFP x VAF`

`UFP` = Sum of all the complexities i.e. the 5 parameters provided in the question,
`VAF` = Value added Factor i.e. `0.65 + (0.01 * TDI)`,
`TDI` = Total Degree of Influence of the 14 General System Characteristics.

[image: functional-points calculation]

Thus function points can be calculated as:

```
= (200 + 200 + 140 + 60 + 28) x (0.65 + (0.01 x (14 x 3))
= 628 x (0.65 + 0.42)
= 628 x (1.07)
= 672
```

> Thus the function points for the project will be **672**.

---

Checkout this [**article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18024/Calculating-Function-Points) for a detailed walk-through into function-point calculations.